# How to add sentence numbering for tokenised words in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I currently have a dataframe with a column of already tokenized words and other columns with tags:

```
  token      tag
1    I        PRN
2    like     VBD
3    apples   NNP
4    .         .
5    John     PRN
6    likes    VBD
7    pears    NNP
8     .        .
```

I would like to add sentence numbering within the df, by adding an extra column:

```
  token      tag   sentence #
1    I        PRN  sentence 1
2    like     VBD  sentence 1
3    apples   NNP  sentence 1
4    .         .   sentence 1
5    John     PRN  sentence 2
6    likes    VBD  sentence 2
7    pears    NNP  sentence 2
8     .        .   sentence 2
```

I am working with a human annotated dataset that has been pre-tokenized. I already tried de-tokenizing it, adding the sentence count and then re-tokenizing it; which gave me an entirely different token count, unfortunately. This method would results in the tag columns not aligning with the token column.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Good Morning,

If what you would like to do is add in the sentence that contains the work and the token, I would suggest adding a primary key reference to the sentence that you are doing your parsing from. I would love to help more, but unless i you the method that you are using to get the tokens and tag I cannot assist any further. I have given a methodized approach below. Are you using a self built method/module? Are you using a package/module that is in Sci-Kit learn to tokenize strings? Have a lovely day!

My Approach:

- Take the dataset
- Clean the dataset
- Assign a reference/GUID key to each phrase that is being tokenized
- Run tokenizing method
- Do a join on the two data sets to create the model view that you want.

Comment: Good morning, thank you for your suggestion! I am working with a human annotated dataset that has been pre-tokenized. I already tried de-tokenizing it, adding the sentence count and then re-tokenising it; which gave me an entirely different token count, unfortunately.